# Remove cache data if array is empty in LoadManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an array which populate my RecyclerView. I used LoadManager in getting data from database and everything is working fine when my array is not empty.

This is my code for calling LoaderManager.

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null,loaderCallbacks);`

 private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<BidCategoryItemsClass>> loaderCallbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<BidCategoryItemsClass>>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<ArrayList<BidCategoryItemsClass>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new BidCategoryItemsLoader(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<BidCategoryItemsClass>> loader, ArrayList<BidCategoryItemsClass> data) {
        adapter.swapData(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<BidCategoryItemsClass>> loader) {

    }
};

public static class BidCategoryItemsLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<BidCategoryItemsClass>> {

    public BidCategoryItemsLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartLoading() {
            forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<BidCategoryItemsClass> loadInBackground() {
        getData();
        ArrayList posting_items = new ArrayList<>();

        if (items!=null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                BidCategoryItemsClass data = new BidCategoryItemsClass();
                data.set_item_name(items[i]);
                data.set_image(image[i]);
                posting_items.add(data);
            }
        }

        return posting_items;
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(ArrayList<BidCategoryItemsClass> data) {
        super.deliverResult(data);}
}`
```

My question is how to remove cache data of LoadManager output since it retain the latest data (when I click another item of my gridview) when the result of array is empty. I used this code in every item thats why I used restartLoader(). I can't really figure out where to remove the cache or whatever it caused this. Thank you in advance for helping.